# How to pass string with whitespaces to msi package

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have Basic MSI InstallShield project. I want to pass parameter to my setup.exe and assign its value to a Property. For this purpose I added a new Property **MY_PROPERTY** in Property Manager view.

Then I can run my setup and set value of MY_PROPERTY:

```
setup.exe /v"MY_PROPERTY=ValueOfProperty"
```

And it works for me.

But if I'm running the same command and trying to pass string that contains whitespaces:

```
setup.exe /v"MY_PROPERTY=Value Of Property"
```

it doesn't work (it starts extracting MSI but suddenly Windows Installer Dialog appears with description of different Install Options and other Help info and I cannot continue installation)

Any ideas, please, how to pass string that contains whitespaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.exe /v"MY_PROPERTY=\"Value Of Property\""` works for me.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Christopher.